# How to resolve "could not create/delete. make sure all files from that directory are closed"

Tags: windows-7, crm

installing Pivotal CRM for my Windows 7 machine and it gave me this error message. It was working the other day but yesterday it went askew so I uninstalled everything and tried reinstalling to find this error message:

"could not create/delete. [PATH TO MY TEMP FILES] make sure all files from that directory are closed"

Any one faced this before or know how to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated :)

UPDATE: I half found what was wrong, there's a missing file called iafconfig.xml it's meant to have.. anyone know where I can manually get one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the mystery!

For anyone else who has this problem:

step one:

Go to C:/users/[YOUR USERNAME]/appdata/

You should see various folders like "temp", There also should be one called CDC software, you won't be able to delete this because something else is using it, so cut and paste it to your desktop and THEN install the CRM and it will install.

Hope this helps anyone who has similar issues :)